# Can I see why my comments disappeared?

Tags: discussion, comments

In this question, there were several comments on my answer: [Calling a Qt function from the Javascript side (QWebView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469295/calling-a-qt-function-from-the-javascript-side-qwebview/19469476#19469476), one of which had been upvoted a few times. Now today when I look, the comments are gone and are even missing from my activity view.

I suppose some moderator or someone deleted them, but is it possible to see someone exactly why they were deleted? Or do I require more privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All five comments were flagged as obsolete, and deleted by a moderator.  Apparently they had already served their purpose.  I looked through the deleted comments, but didn't see any information in them that would be useful to anyone else.  Only moderators get to review this kind of activity.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just my first experience with things disappearing like this. I agree that they weren't useful, just a curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

As the moderator who deleted them I can tell you where they went and why: 
They were flagged as obsolete and I agreed.

Of the five comments on the post when I viewed it they were all either

1. Thanks
2. Included in your answer as an edit already.

Thus I agreed with the flag and removed them.

Comments are ephemeral - these comments had clearly served their purpose (quite usefully) but their continued existence now offered no lasting value. In fact once they had been acted upon they only clutter up the post and add a now irrelevant historical perspective.